# Excel-insert cell value at another cell each time

Tags: excel

I have some specific (different) numbers which will be the lead-time of the order to arrive to e.g. a warehouse, meaning that the lead-time is stochastic. I want the "ordered quantity" to be inserted "x" rows down at the "order arrival" column. For example, as seen in the photo, I want the "100" ordered quality to be inserted two rows down at "order arrival", and afterwards "120" to be inserted 5 rows down at "order arrival".

Is there a way to do that with a function in excel?Any ideas? Thanks 1

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUlzm.jpg)

Comment: There is a way to do this with Excel - where do the "stochastic" data come from for the order lead-times?  Is it from a probability distribution?  Is it a look-up based on type of item, etc?

Comment: Exactly, I have used this function "=CEILING((NORMINV(RAND(),6,2)),1)", so a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the screenshot and code sample below will help you get started.  I cannot think of a way to do what you want without using macros though I am sure there are some experts on here who may be able to come up with an amazing formula!

Please see the screenshot attached below.  I have reformatted your table slightly for the purposes of demonstration, so now it looks like this:

[image]

I then wrote the following macro.  Its a very rough-and-ready macro as Im at work and about to go home, but it should get you started:

```
Sub runorders()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D1000").ClearContents

readrow = 2
currentday = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & readrow).Value
currentleadtime = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & readrow).Value
currentorderquantity = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & readrow).Value

Do Until currentday = ""

    If currentorderquantity <> "" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & readrow + currentleadtime).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & readrow + currentleadtime).Value + currentorderquantity
    End If

readrow = readrow + 1
currentday = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & readrow).Value
currentleadtime = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & readrow).Value
currentorderquantity = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & readrow).Value

Loop

End Sub
```

Obviously for the code to work you will need the workbook set up exactly as I have done so in the screenshot.  The cells highlighted in orange will need your normaldistribution formula.  Don't forget that each time the macro writes the "order arrival" value into a cell in column d, the random distribution values will change (e.g. re-sample) unless you do something about it.

I hope this helps!

Paul

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot my friend. That will save a lot of time.

Comment: Although there is an issue. It sometimes overwrites the values in the cell in the case where 2 orders arrive the same day, while it should sum the two values in that cell.

Comment: Ah yes - as I say, I wrote it in a hurry!  Just edit the line inside the "if" statement so that it says:  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & readrow + currentleadtime).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & readrow + currentleadtime).Value + currentorderquantity and that should do it.  Ive edited my answer as well to make it reflect the latest/most correct code.